# Use Raspberry Pi Zero WH as keyboard HID driver at boot

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w, keyboard, archlinux, hid

### Background

My keyboard, a Majestouch Convertible 2, has Bluetooth capabilities such that it can connect up to 4 devices. My primary driver and the 1st device the keyboard is connected to is my desktop, running Arch Linux. I will eventually have a small partition dedicated to Windows, for some proprietary software that does not run well with Wine.

To switch between the two, I will be dual booting. At boot, however, the keyboard does not connect to anything. I have read that this is due to Bluetooth capability not being possible until *after* the display manager has loaded.

### Desired outcome

I would like the keyboard to take 3 Bluetooth states; Arch, GRUB, and Windows. The first and last of these is trivial. The second state I was envisioning completing by using the Raspberry Pi Zero WH (herein **rpi0**).

Thus, when the keyboard is connected to the rpi0, which itself is connected to the PC, the computer instead believes this to be a USB keyboard, allowing keypresses to be recognised at boot, and therefore to switch operating systems in the GRUB menu.

A table to illustrate the desired outcome:

| Keyboard | Connection | Bridge | Connection | PC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Majestouch Convertible 2 (Bluetooth state 2) | Bluetooth | rpi0 | USB | Arch Linux |

### What has been tried

Firstly, connecting the keyboard directly to the PC with its supplied USB does work and register my keypresses. For the purposes of this project, however, I would like all connections to be completed over

After flashing the OS to my SD and running the rpi0 for the first time, I connected my keyboard to the device via Bluetooth, and this does work. So Bluetooth state 2 is currently paired and trusted by the rpi0 and connect without issue.

To test this, I have connected the rpi0 to a screen.

I have purchased a proprietary plug for the rpi0 to power itself, and I have also powered the rpi0 by using the **other** USB port (that is, **not** the power port) and connecting directly to the PC. Both of these methods supply power to the rpi0 and allow it to boot.

Making my system recognise the rpi0 as a USB keyboard (or a driver for one) does not work, unfortunately. I have also followed the repository [here](https://github.com/mikerr/pihidproxy) although I appreciate it is quite old and does not, for instance, use `systemd` units, amongst other things. This too does not work, it seems.

Other questions mentioning a similar issue seem to refer back to the guide [here](http://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383), though this was written in 2016 and its information seems somewhat out of date.

### Core issue

So I am wondering, given the above, how I might be able to configure and use my rpi0 such that it is recognised by my system as a USB keyboard for the purposes of navigating the GRUB menu.